# How to use separate in tidyverse to split a column?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I use `separate()` function to split column: Enterdateofexam2, it is character format, the value is like "25.07","13.09","16.06"... My aim is splitting it into day(25) and month(07), then use convert = true to turn them into numeric for filter in next step.

My code is:

```
jimma3n <- jimma3 %>%
        select(Enterdateofexam2, Enterdayofexam, UniqueKey,MEDICALRECORD)%>%
        separate(Enterdateofexam2,into=c("day", "month"), sep=".", convert = TRUE)
view (jimma3n)
```

but the R keeps warning me like:

```
Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 4088 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].
```

So could anyone help to figure out which part is wrong about my code? Thanks~~!

Comment: Could you post your `dput(head(data))` please?

Comment: I ran that, it shows :  structure(list(Enterdateofexam2 = list(c("", "7.06"), c("", "8.06"
), c("", "9.06"), c("", "2.12"), c("", "3.12"), c("", "4.12")), 
    Enterdayofexam = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), UniqueKey = c("530", 
    "530", "530", "531", "531", "531"), MEDICALRECORD = c("577207", 
    "577207", "577207", "575333", "575333", "575333")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), why there is ("",...) in front of the number, how can I remove "" and only keep the value in the column? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is because your `Enterdateofexam2` is loaded as a list in your `data.frame`, this is why you get the error!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `extra` argument.  Also, by default, the `sep` is in `regex` mode - according to `?separate` documentation

> sep - If character, sep is interpreted as a regular expression. The default value is a regular expression that matches any sequence of non-alphanumeric values.

and `.` is a metacharacter which can match any character.  Therefore, we may need to either escape (`\\.`) or place it in square brackets (`[.]`).  Also, based on the `dput`, the column is a `list`, which should be `unnest`ed first before doing the `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
jimma3 %>%
      select(Enterdateofexam2, Enterdayofexam, UniqueKey,MEDICALRECORD)%>%
      unnest(Enterdateofexam2) %>%
      separate(Enterdateofexam2,into=c("day", "month"), 
              sep="\\.", convert = TRUE, extra = "merge") %>% 
      na.omit
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
    day month Enterdayofexam UniqueKey MEDICALRECORD
  <int> <int> <chr>          <chr>     <chr>        
1     7     6 1              530       577207       
2     8     6 2              530       577207       
3     9     6 3              530       577207       
4     2    12 1              531       575333       
5     3    12 2              531       575333       
6     4    12 3              531       575333
```

Basically, with `sep = "."`, it is splitting at every character element and thus the warning popped up

#### data

```
jimma3 <- structure(list(Enterdateofexam2 = list(c("", "7.06"), c("", "8.06"
), c("", "9.06"), c("", "2.12"), c("", "3.12"), c("", "4.12")), 
    Enterdayofexam = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"), UniqueKey = c("530", 
    "530", "530", "531", "531", "531"), MEDICALRECORD = c("577207", 
    "577207", "577207", "575333", "575333", "575333")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

**The main issue is that you have to define the number of columns** you will separate to. If you define 2 columns let's say `a` and `b` and you have 3 elements to separate: let's say `x` `y` `z`, then `z` will be discarded.

With `separate` you must define the new columns, which is difficult if you don't know how many columns you will need after `separate`

Consider this example:
in row 3 you have 3 elements:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("x", "x y", "x y z", NA))
      x
1     x
2   x y
3 x y z
4  <NA>
```

With this code you define 2 columns to separate to

```
df %>% separate(x, c("a", "b"))

     a    b
1    x <NA>
2    x    y
3    x    y
4 <NA> <NA>
```

In row 3 `z` is discarded because we have define only 2 columns `a` and `b`

If we define 3 columns like

`df %>% separate(x, c("a", "b", "c"))`

The warning for discarding will disappear.

On the other hand you will get a warning for x with fewer then 3 elements, those will be filled with NA.